# Plot a JPG image using base graphics in R

Tags: r

I am searching for a simple way to plot a photographic JPEG image on a graphics device in R.

For example the following using the `raster` package appears to ignore the colour attributes in the image.  I want to reproduce the photograph in its original colours:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

myJPG <- raster("colourfulPic.jpg")
plot(myJPG)  ## Recolours JPEG;
```

I have discovered that the package `rimage` has recently been archived and appears to no longer be recommended for use (see [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Asking-About-packages-quot-rimage-quot-td4395719.html)), if it, indeed, ever did what I need.

Similarly the `EBImage` for BioConductor, which may also possibly work, is not built for 64 bit Windows, and unfortunately I need this architecture.

Please tell me I missing something very obvious in base graphics?

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `rimage`, perhaps use the package `ReadImages`:

```
library('ReadImages')
myjpg <- read.jpeg('E:/bigfoot.jpg')
plot(myjpg)
```

Comment: I knew it would be simple!  Sometimes finding the right package is all it takes.  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW If you care about performance or memory usage, using `readJPEG(..., native=TRUE)` from `jpeg` to read and then `rasterImage` from `graphics` to plot is much more efficient for large images as it avoids all the unnecessary conversions into arrays that `ReadImages` does.

Comment: Unfortunately, the package `ReadImages` is orphaned and no longer available on CRAN. It has not been updated to work with R versions 2.14.0 and newer.

Answer (score 33):

Here goes an updated solution, that relies only on the `jpeg` package and handles color and greyscale images (**packages used in other solutions are outdated and won't install with a recent R version**).

The solution consists in this plot function:

```
plot_jpeg = function(path, add=FALSE)
{
  require('jpeg')
  jpg = readJPEG(path, native=T) # read the file
  res = dim(jpg)[2:1] # get the resolution, [x, y]
  if (!add) # initialize an empty plot area if add==FALSE
    plot(1,1,xlim=c(1,res[1]),ylim=c(1,res[2]),asp=1,type='n',xaxs='i',yaxs='i',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab='',ylab='',bty='n')
  rasterImage(jpg,1,1,res[1],res[2])
}
```

This function can then be called with the path of the picture as argument, for example:

```
plot_jpeg('~/nyancat.jpg')
```

To add the picture to an existing plot, use the switch `add=TRUE` - and be wary of axis limits!

Comment: I had to invert the resolution in order to get a correct plot. Change res = dim(jpg)[1:2] to res = dim(jpg)[2:1] OR replace all res[1] with res[2] and vice versa to fix the error

Answer (score 10):

Using the `imager` package:

```
library(imager)

image <- load.image(image_filename)
plot(image)
```

This works for a number of image formats including `jpeg`, `gif`, etc...

Answer (score 4):

If you are building an RMarkdown document, `knitr::include_graphics()` is direct and simple.

Answer (score 0):

`raster` Has a built-in function for this called `plotRGB`

```
library(raster)  
myJPG <- stack("colourfulPic.jpg")  
plotRGB(myJPG)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Please note that `ReadImages` is now deprecated. Instead you could install the [biOps package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biOps/index.html), which also contains a rich set of image manipulation methods. Use as follows:

```
library(jpeg)
library(biOps)

image <- readJPEG("test.jpg")

# image is of type imagedata (the red,green,blue channel images concatenated)

plot(image)
```

Edit: An object of type `imagedata` is accessed as `image[Y,X,Channel]`, btw

Comment: NOTE: BiOps is now deprecated also. Is there any easy way to plot a JPEG image? There seems to be a lot of data with the package 'jpeg' and takes much CPU usage to plot.

Comment: @ratioVenandi: I got the same problem today, and I just proposed another solution that does not rely on `biOps` or `ReadImages`