# Generating PDF from multiple JPEGs in R

Tags: r, pdf-generation

I have a folder with multiple JPEG files. How do I generate a PDF file from these JPEGs in R?

One JPEG = 1 PDF page. Images are of the same size.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use R to do this?

Comment: I have an R script that downloads JPEGs automatically, want to put them into a PDF. Would like to do everything with one tool.

Comment: Does using a `system` call to something like Ghostscript count as using "one tool"? ;)

Comment: Is there no native support of PDF generation in R? Why use Ghostscript?

Comment: @dmitryungurean There is PDF generation in R, but it's simply an output mode for graphics, it doesn't - AFAIK - support any control over the structure of the produced document. I would have the R script call some kind of external tool to do this.

Comment: It's not the native support for PDF generation that bothers me. It is the effort that would be required to read the JPEGs in in a format that R can recognize before being able to plot it as a PDF. Using Ghostscript it's as easy as specifying your output file and providing a list of input files that need to be combined.

Comment: Would [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543343/plot-a-jpg-image-using-base-graphics-in-r) help with reading in the jpegs? It sounds like @AnandaMahto might be justified in suggesting Ghostscript from a performance standpoint, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using Latex. Which is nice, because then you can just use Sweave to do the whole thing.

You can do something along the lines of :

```
% This is some Sweave file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

<<results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
mypics <- dir('mypics')
for(i in mypics){
cat("\\includegraphics{", i, "}\n\n", sep = "")
}
@
\end{document}
```

OK, you'll have to set up your Sweave pipeline, but with a bit of tweaking you can automate the whole process easily.

Comment: Thanks Joris I'll try Latex + Sweave. Completely new to it:)

Answer (score 1):

if you insist on using R (other tools are more suitable), try something like this (slow, untested):

```
   lf = list.files(pattern = "jpeg") # image filenames

   library(jpeg)
   jpegs = lapply(lf, readJPG)

   library(grid)
   pdf("output.pdf", width=8, height=4)
   grid.raster(jpegs[[1]])
   lapply(jpegs[-1], function(x) {grid.newpage() ; grid.raster(x)} ) -> bquiet
   dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using R to do this then you can open a `pdf` plotting device, `par` to set the margins (default will probably be to big and not centering), then in a loop use `plot.new` to start a new page and `plot.window` to set up the coordinates, etc. without plotting axes etc., use the `read.jpeg` function from the ReadImages package (or other tool/package to read, EBImage is another possibility) then `rasterImage` to plot the jpeg to the pdf device (or replace some of those steps with other image plotting functions, such as the plot method in ReadImages).

But overall it is probably easier/quicker/better/... to use a tool better designed for this type of thing.  The ImageMagick suite of programs comes to mind, LaTeX has also been mentioned, and there are probably other tools as well.