# Displaying images in R in version 3.1.0

Tags: r, image

I've ran into old stackoverflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543343/plot-a-jpg-image-using-base-graphics-in-r) that use packages like ReadImages and biOps that are now deprecated in R 3.1.0, and are not available anymore.

Can someone tell me how to display an image in R 3.1.0? (Specifically jpeg and png images)

Answer (score 22):

As pointed out by Simon Urbanek in [the comments of the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543343/plot-a-jpg-image-using-base-graphics-in-r#comment12100312_9543424), you can do this:

```
library("jpeg")
jj <- readJPEG("myfile.jpg",native=TRUE)
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
rasterImage(jj,0,0,1,1)
```

or (for PNG)

```
library("png")
pp <- readPNG("myfile.png")
plot.new() 
rasterImage(pp,0,0,1,1)
```

version 0.1.7 of `png`, 0.1.8 of `jpeg`

Answer (score 19):

The package [`imager`](http://dahtah.github.io/imager/) can load png, jpeg and bmp images.

```
library(imager)
im<-load.image("myimage")
plot(im)
```

It has also many functions for processing and plotting. With extra libraries installed (ffmpeg and ImageMagick), it can even load videos and other images format.