# how to download and display an image from an URL in R?

Tags: r, image, url, download

My goal is to download an image from an URL and then display it in R.

I got an URL and figured out how to download it. But the downloaded file can't be previewed because it is 'damaged, corrupted, or is too big'.

```
y = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/AaronEckhart10TIFF.jpg"
download.file(y, 'y.jpg')
```

I also tried

```
image('y.jpg')
```

in R, but the error message shows like:

```
Error in image.default("y.jpg") : argument must be matrix-like
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems the underlying problem is the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655361/download-png-jpg-with-r)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I try your code it looks like the image is downloaded. However, when opened with windows image viewer it also says it is corrupt.
The reason for this is that you don't have specified the `mode` in the `download.file` statement.

Try this:

```
download.file(y,'y.jpg', mode = 'wb')
```

For more info about the mode is see `?download.file`

This way at least the file that you downloaded is working.

To view the image in R, have a look at

```
jj <- readJPEG("y.jpg",native=TRUE)
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
rasterImage(jj,0,0,1,1)
```

or [how to read.jpeg in R 2.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283447/how-to-read-jpeg-in-r-2-15)
 or [Displaying images in R in version 3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861000/displaying-images-in-r-in-version-3-1-0?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks! It works now. An follow up question: what should i do if I don't want to download (save) the jpeg file on the disk but just save it to the workplace?

Comment: You can download the image as a temporary file. Please accept the first answer if this answers your original question

Comment: After adding the arg `mode = 'wb'`, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this could work too 
here

```
library("jpeg")

library("png")

x <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/AaronEckhart10TIFF.jpg"    

image_name<- readJPEG(getURLContent(x)) # for jpg

image_name<- readPNG(getURLContent(x)) # for png
```

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the image, you can use base R to open the file using your default image viewer program like this:

```
file.show(yourfilename)
```