# R: Download image using rvest

Tags: r, download, rcurl, rvest, httr

I'm attempting to download a `png` image from a secure site through R.

To access the secure site I used `Rvest` which worked well.

So far I've extracted the URL for the `png` image.

How can I download the image of this link using rvest?

Functions outside of the `rvest` function return errors due to not having permission.

### Current attempts

```
library(rvest)
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://url.png", user_agent(uastring))
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
form <- set_values(form, username = "***", password="***", cookie_checkbox= TRUE)
session<-submit_form(session, form)
session2<-jump_to(session, "https://url.png")

## Status 200 using rvest, sucessfully accsessed page.    
session 
<session> https://url.png
  Status: 200
  Type:   image/png
  Size:   438935

## Using download.file returns status 403, page unable to open.
download.file("https://url.png", destfile = "t.png")
    cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Have tried `readPNG` and `download.file` on the url, both of which failed due to not having permission to download from a authenticated secure site (error: 403), hence why I used rvest in the first place.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110903/how-to-download-and-display-an-image-from-an-url-in-r) helpful

Comment: The problem he's having isn't with downloading a file, it's with the authentication part. He may have to use `httr::GET` with a cookie or other authentication mechanism.

Comment: @cory, it is indeed an authentication issue. I've used rvest to access the site successfully, however functions outside of Rvest still fail to access the site and download the PNG

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one example to download the R logo into the current directory.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.r-project.org"
imgsrc <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*/img') %>%
  html_attr('src')
imgsrc
# [1] "/Rlogo.png"

# side-effect!
download.file(paste0(url, imgsrc), destfile = basename(imgsrc))
```

**EDIT**

Since authentication is involved, Austin's suggestion of using a session is certainly required. Try this:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
sess <- html_session(url)
imgsrc <- sess %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*/img') %>%
  html_attr('src')
img <- jump_to(sess, paste0(url, imgsrc))

# side-effect!
writeBin(img$response$content, basename(imgsrc))
```

Comment: I've already attempted using download.file with the URL directly, the issue is that it returns `error:403 forbidden` and is not able to open the link. Hence why I needed to use rvest initially to get a response 200.

Comment: Your post said that `download.file` wasn't working because it was a secure site. My example is accessing a secure site and works. Is there authentication involved, or is it just session-tracking or url-referer problems?

Comment: Apologies, I meant there is authentication involved (as well as being secure). Using rvest I've managed to submit the authentication and got a status 200, but when trying to use functions outside of the R package to download it returns error 403.

Comment: @G.Gip, I am inferring that this isn't working for you based on your question edit. However, your edit is still using `download.file`, which my second method changed. Your image is stored in your `session` variable (if the form submission returns just an image) or `session2` (otherwise), so you should be able to use `session$response$content` as I demonstrated in my answer. If this doesn't work, perhaps you can tell us what happens when you do it? (Regardless, stop using `download.file`, it obviously won't meet your needs.)

Comment: It worked, brilliant response! Do you know if it would possible to pass multiple sessions / PNG urls to writeBin()? My idea of using R was to use it as a batch downloader of the images.

Comment: Because `writeBin` is taking the full body of the response, you would need to do multiple calls to `jump_to(session, ...)` with a `writeBin` for each. It may be feasible with pipelining, but that may be beyond what `rvest`/`httr` can do (and certainly beyond my knowledge at the moment). You might be able to reuse the session from the first call and make direct (non-form) connections for the others, assuming they are all behind the same auth. In that case, it should be relatively trivial to automate it ("batch" is up for interpretation).

Answer (score 6):

Try this example below:

```
library(rvest); library(dplyr)

url <- "http://www.calacademy.org/explore-science/new-discoveries-an-alaskan-butterfly-a-spider-physicist-and-more"
webpage <- html_session(url)
link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")

img.url <- link.titles[13] %>% html_attr("src")

download.file(img.url, "test.jpg", mode = "wb")
```

You now have "test.jpg" which is the picture:[image]

Comment: Hi Austin. I've tried a similar method, unfortunately `download.file()` returns error 403: forbidden as authentication is required, hence why I required rvest to access the page.

Comment: `rvest` imports `%>%`, so you don't need `dplyr` for this answer. Other than showing the jpeg itself, was this supposed to do anything differently than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Works with several queries, renames the file, and registers the link in a Txt file.
For queries with space use a + in between, see in the example.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(httr)

search_and_download_images <- function(query, size, n_images = 2, output_directory = "downloaded_images") {
  # Prepare the query for Google Images search
  search_url <- paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=", query, "&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m")
  
  # Scrape image URLs from Google Images
  image_links <- search_url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("img") %>%
    html_attr("src") %>%
    na.omit()
  
  # Keep the desired number of image URLs
  image_links <- image_links[1:min(n_images, length(image_links))]
  
  # Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
  if (!dir.exists(output_directory)) {
    dir.create(output_directory)
  }
  
  # Download and save images
  for (i in 2:length(image_links)) {
    img_url <- image_links[i]
    response <- GET(img_url)
    
    if (response$status_code == 200) {
      file_ext <- tools::file_ext(img_url)
      if (file_ext == "") {
        file_ext <- "jpg"
      }
      
      # Save the image
      img_filename <- file.path(output_directory, paste0(query, "_", i, ".", file_ext))
      writeBin(content(response, "raw"), img_filename)
      
      # Save image information (URL, local filename)
      info_filename <- file.path(output_directory, paste0(query, "_", i, "_info.txt"))
      cat(paste("URL:", img_url, "\n"), file = info_filename)
      cat(paste("Local file:", img_filename, "\n"), file = info_filename, append = TRUE)
    } else {
      cat(paste("Failed to download image", i, "for query", query, "\n"))
    }
  }
}


# research_terms <- c("Water erosion", "wind erosion")
research_terms <- c("Water+erosion", "wind+erosion")
desired_size <- "medium"
number_of_images <- 10

for (term in research_terms) {
  search_and_download_images(term, size = desired_size, n_images = number_of_images)
}
```