# How to download a Wikipedia image for a species page

Tags: r, wikipedia-api

I routinely want images of organisms to complement datasets and it would be great if I could pull out a species image for, say a bottlenose dolphin, given the Genus and species. I would then use this image in a K12 educational Shiny App similar to [this one](https://wilkins.shinyapps.io/bird_vocal_scaling/) for students to explore the dataset. I found a way to get the URL and some page info with the `WikipediR` package, but I can't figure out how to extract the URL for the image in the sidebar.

```
require(WikipediR)
page_info("en","wikipedia",page="Tursiops truncatus")
```

I know there's a way (i.e. [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo)), but I don't really understand how to make this work in R.

Comment: I don't think you need to use WikipediaR package or even the Wikimedia API. I would just suggest using rvest, similar to this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202414/r-download-image-using-rvest

Comment: Thanks, so much for pointing me in this direction! This led me to what I was looking for! Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Stedy's suggestion, I found a solution. Note there are 2 similarly named Wikipedia interface packages for R. This one uses WikipediR, not WikipediaR.

```
require(WikipediR); require(rvest)

#titles= vector of page name(s)
#res= desired width in pixels (220 px thumbnail by default)
#savedest= save destination (w terminal '/'); wd by default

getwikipic<-function(titles,res,savedest){
    if(missing(res)){res=220}
    if(missing(savedest)){savedest=NA}
  lapply(titles, function (ttl,...){
  d<-page_info("en","wikipedia",page=ttl,clean_response=T)
  url<-d[[1]]$fullurl
  wikipage<-html_session(url)
  imginfo<-wikipage %>% html_nodes("tr:nth-child(2) img")
  img.url<- imginfo[1] %>% html_attr("src")
  img.url<-paste0("https:",img.url)
  if(is.na(savedest)){
    savefilename<-paste0(ttl,".jpg")
    }else{savefilename<-paste0(savedest,ttl,".jpg")}

  if(res!=220){img.url<-gsub(220,res,img.url)}  

  download.file(img.url,savefilename)
  return(paste0("orig.file: ",basename(img.url)))#tell user original filename (or error)

  },res,savedest)#End lapply
}#End function
```

---

Alternatively, I created a GitHub repo with the code [here](https://github.com/drwilkins/getwikipic). You can source and run this quite simply in R.

```
devtools::source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drwilkins/getwikipic/master/getwikipic.R")

titles<-c("numbat")
getwikipic(titles,1024)
```

Downloads this to your working directory
 [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84GFp.jpg)

Comment: since your code isn't that long, could you please post (i.e. cut and paste) it here in addition to providing the Github link?  SO strongly encourages making answers as self-contained as possible ...

Comment: No problem. Code added!