# How I can load and display an Image from URL in R? "Cant Load EBImage in R 3.4.4"

Tags: r, image

Im trying to download and show an image from an URL in R.. but the package im tryin to use is not available in my version of R:

Im trying this:

```
library(EBImage)

img = readImage("https://www.yr.no/assets/images/logo-yr-50.png")
display(img, method = "raster")
```

Previously, when I try to install the package:

```
install.packages("EBImage")

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘EBImage’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

Is there another package to download and show the Image in R?

PS: Im new in R.

Comment: EBImage seems to be in BioConductor, not on the standard R package repository - CRAN - see here https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html and check the 'Installation' section.

Comment: You may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110903/how-to-download-and-display-an-image-from-an-url-in-r) helpful.

Comment: `magick::image_read("https://www.yr.no/assets/images/logo-yr-50.png")`