# Print/Show JPG file in R

Tags: r, jpeg, rvest

While using `rvest` package I am trying to print/show the [lego_movie](http://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/rvest.html) poster in R. I fail to do so. Here's my attempts:

```
library(rvest)
poster <- lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("#img_primary img") %>%
  html_attr("src")

## 1st attempt
library(jpeg)
jpeg(poster)
dev.off()

## 2nd attempt
readJPEG(poster)
dev.off()
```

I think [EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/EBImage/man/EBImage.pdf) has `display` function. This package can't be installed in `R-3.1.2`. It shows the warning message: `package ‘EBImage’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`.

The bottom line of my question is: how to see the jpeg file in R as a display without using `EBImage` package?

Few related questions:

[Plot a JPG image using base graphics in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543343/plot-a-jpg-image-using-base-graphics-in-r)

[How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: what's `lego_movie`?

Comment: By the way, `EBImage` is [available](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html)

Comment: @SubasishDas you used `lego_movie` without showing where it came from. _I_ know it's from the `rvest` example code, but others _won't_.

Comment: @SubasishDas `lego_movie` is from http://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/rvest.html

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I have edited again from your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Is @hrbrmstr's answer useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some starter code you can build on:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(jpeg)

lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

poster <- lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("#img_primary img") %>%
  html_attr("src")

GET(poster, write_disk("lego.jpg"))
img <- readJPEG("lego.jpg")
plot(1:2, type='n')
rasterImage(img, 1, 1.25, 1.1, 1)
```

Comment: Paul Murrell added a plot method for raster images in r-devel, so in the future you'll be able to do `plot(img)`